# extract text between string - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string:

```
<iframe src="keep-url" width="125" height="290" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

I want to remove all except:

```
keep-url
```

and using Javascript, jquery, with jsfiddle
Thank you.

Comment: Correct me, but if you remove *everything* from a string except "keep-url", then why not simply change the string to "keep-url", if the original string contains it?

Comment: I think, question should be how to get specific question from string. It should be resolved using regex

Comment: but, i have some strings with different `url`

Comment: Try this `var src = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].getAttribute('src');`

Comment: My string just a pure text, it's not <iframe> tag, you can see https://jsfiddle.net/ducrat/yhq1v31e/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to extract text from the string, you can get the `src` attribute from the element:

```js
var src = $('<iframe src="keep-url" width="125" height="290" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>').attr('src');

console.log(src);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to create the element (without adding to the document) and get the attrribute:

```
$src = $(theString).attr('src');
```

Comment: @Rajesh "Concurrency is hard" :-)